# Change canvas size in processing.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, processing, processing.js

I have the code in my html file:

```
    <p><canvas id="canvas1" width="1000" height="200"></canvas></p>
```

but changing the width and height doesn't affect the canvas size at all. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a canvas' dimensions in both css and javascript as well.

The documentation for Processing.js shows a function named setup():
http://processingjs.org/reference/size_/

Find where your script is calling that and set your own values.